# string handling in C with pointer

Tags: c, string

this my code and when i run it using gcc compiler on linux machine and still showing those eroor bellow

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

 int is_in_f(char *s, char c) {
 while(*s) {
    if(*s==c) return 1;
    else s++;
}
return 0;
}

int main() {
char *name = "paria llls";
char string1[] = "a";
if(is_in_f(*name, string1)){
    printf("found");
}

return 0;
}
```

this my error

```
 E2.c: In function ‘main’:
 E2.c:14:19: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘is_in_f’ makes integer from          pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  if(is_in_f(name, string1)){
               ^~~~~~~
E2.c:3:5: note: expected ‘char’ but argument is of type ‘char *’
int is_in_f(char *s, char c) {
```

Comment: Hint: `*name` is the same as `name[0]`.

Comment: @molbdnilo How are they different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made two errors in your call:

- When you pass a pointer to a parameter that needs a pointer of the same type, do not use dereference operator `*`, and
- The type for variables that keep a single character is `char`, not array of `char`. Constants of type `char` are delimited with single quotes instead of double quotes.

Hence, the calling code should be as follows:

```
char *name = "paria llls";
char char1 = 'a'; // <<== Note single quotes
if(is_in_f(name, char1 )) { // <<== No asterisk
    ...
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot but i wanted to ask how can found the index at which the character has been found. in python i could have made something like this s[c] in my is_in_f function but in C it return null

Comment: @pariaslunkamba Make a temporary variable, and use it as a pointer: `char *p = s; while(*p) { if(*p==c) return (p-s); else p++;} return -1;`

Comment: thinks bro i dont like C that much and jumped to python and java, the more i dig deeper i finally found how C was important now im back at again revising. because these other languages have some limitations

Comment: @pariaslunkamba No problem! Learning C after Python is tough, because the language is at the lowest level among high-level languages.

Answer (score 0):

When you're calling the function `is_in_f()`, you are passing `name*` which is a character as the variable `name` is a pointer variable. And you are defined in the function definition as the `char *s`, which is an address to the `character` in `pointer variable` are incompatible.

In the second parameter at the time of calling, you're passing the starting **address** of the array of character `string1` and defined as the `char`, so here also they are incompatible.

Check this working code, a little modified of yours. Hope it helped.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

 int is_in_f(char *s, char *c) {
 while(*s) {
    if(*s==*c) return 1;
    else s++;
}
return 0;
}

int main() {
char *name = "paria llls";
char string1[] = "a";
if(is_in_f(name, string1)){
    printf("found");
}

return 0;
}
```